# how to retrieve images or files from a certain route page in laravel?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I am having issues displaying or retrieving user profile photo at certain routes. it works perfectly for other views especially that main views. photos fails to appear when i try to display on a certain view but make changes to the route.

**example: 1** if i try displaying or retrieving images from my database with this view and route, it will fail

```
Route::get('staff/staffprofile/payslip', function () {
    return view('payslip');
});
```

**example 2:** works using this:

```
Route::get('/payslip', function () {
    return view('payslip');
});
```

This is how i display the photo and it works for ***Example 2***

```
<img src="uploads/{{$stp->image}}">
```

i need assist on how to display on certain routes

Comment: Try adding a `/` on the beginning of your image source: `<img src="/uploads/{{$stp->image}}">`

Comment: I have added some precision in a dedicated answer, if you are interested to see how it works under the hood :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it does not work is the way "pretty URLs" and paths work (relative/absolute).

Try to see your URLs with different depth "levels":

- `/staff/staffprofile/payslip` Would be level 2
- `/payslip` would be level 0

Given the fact that you probably use a "public" folder where you store all your assets and your index.php file, you need to ensure that the webserver will actually use a path relative to your "root" folder, in this case the public folder.

---

Say your images are stored in `.../public/uploads/`. (The `...` are the previous folders in the path)

Depending on how you link your image, the web server will search for the image in a different location:

Without the first forward slash (`uploads/image.png`)

- On `/staff/staffprofile/payslip` : `.../public/staffprofile/payslip/uploads/image.png`
- On `/payslip` : `.../public/uploads/image.png`

Without forward slash, it only works on "level 0" URLs.

Whereas, with a forward slash (`/uploads/image.png`)

- On `/staff/staffprofile/payslip` : `.../public/uploads/image.png`
- On `/payslip` : `.../public/uploads/image.png`

---

I have also learnt it the hard way and figured it out randomly, so I'm glad it helped someone.

Answer (score 0):

If the image was uploaded using the Storage Facade from Laravel, you can use `Storage::url()` to get the absolute url of the image.

If you want to use the relative path, you can either use `/uploads/...` or set the base url with the HTML  tag.